# What does the notation T(n) mean?

Tags: notation

We learned about big O notation, but I often see T(n) as well. For example,

```
public static Comparable[] mergeSort(Comparable[] A, int low, int high) {
  if (low < high) { //at least 2 elements?                //cost = c
    int mid = (low + high)/2;                             //cost = d
    Comparable[] A1 = mergeSort(A, low, mid);             //cost = T(n/2) + e
    Comparable[] A2 = mergeSort(A, mid+1, high);          //cost = T(n/2) + f
    return merge(A1,A2);                                  //cost = g n + h
  }
  .... //cost = i
```

I believe c,d,e,... are meant to be arbitrarily named constants.

What does T(n/2) mean? also how is T notation related to big O?

Comment: From wikipedia article on O-notation: "A function T(n) that will express how long the algorithm will take to run (in some arbitrary measurement of time) in terms of the number of elements in the input set."

Comment: `T(n)`, denoting the *exact* time needed to calculate the data of size `n`. It's very useful when calculate the time needed of a recursive function.

Answer (score 17):

This notation refers to the maximum amount of time (or, more specifically, steps) that a function takes to run.

T(n) may be much more specific than O(n); for example, let's say you have a program that for any input, requires `n^2+n+1` steps to run:

```
T(n) = n^2+n+1
O(n) = n^2
```

More information can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity).

Answer (score 0):

I've personally never seen this notation before, but I suspect it refers to "big-Theta" (Θ), which is both an asymptotic upper-bound (big-O) and an asymptotic lower bound.

Also related: Big-Omega (Ω) is used to denote just an asymptotic lower-bound (mirroring big-O).

Comment: No, T(n) is a more specific O(n). The thing is T(n) is mostly used in math, while O(n) is mostly used in computers. Big O only calculates time complexity of parts that change. So if you had an algorithm that loops through a number n times, and in the same algorithm, you had a part that loops n\*\*2 times. big O will ignore the first part as it never changes. So it will be O(n\*\*2), in the other hand T will be T(n+n\*\*2).